# SPI control for MAX11169

Tags: adc, spi

For the 2nd figure for the [MAX11169](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX11169.pdf), it tells you to have a c̅s̅ pin for each device and share a conversation line.  Why wouldn't one just have two conversation lines, and load DIN as high meaning its waiting for conversation to go high?

To me, this is just essentially duplicating the first method, which is all around better.  Obviously I'm wrong, as they don't have that advised in the datasheet, I just don't know why.

### [image]

### --

[image]

Comment: Both my, and their 2nd way allow for reading of the value from the same instant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For the 2nd figure for the MAX11169, it tells you to have a c̅s̅ pin for each device and share a conversation line. Why wouldn't one just have two conversation lines, and load DIN as high meaning its waiting for conversation to go high?

DMA is a missing key here.

For example, let's suppose you don't want to collect analog data from two channels, but you cant afford to deal with each sample (sample rate is too high to effectively interrupt on each sample). DMA allows you to use a piece of hardware to copy data from one location (ex: SPI rx buffer) to another (ex: memory).

In SPI peripherals which can be data-controlled (vs register controlled), CS is often one of the controllable parameters. This is where having separate CS for each device becomes helpful.

[image: SPI block]

So, if you attach your conversion start to a timer/counter output (no CPU intervention), and your clock your serial data using DMA (no cpu intervention), then you can use your uC for only processing data.

Incidentally, this is sometimes why you don't want to daisy-chain serial devices. Sometimes, it makes the DMA configuration much easier.

DMAs will transfer data in to contiguous pieces of memory. If you daisy chain (without accounting for it in your DMA configuration), you end up with interleaved data. Depending on what you are measuring and why, this can be very problematic for certain kinds of operations (alternatively, sometimes it's very helpful: here's looking at you Complex FFT). Now, some DMAs allow you to chain, link, or change configuration on the go, but what it boils down to is making the physical design match the software design and making both play as well together as possible.

Answer (score 1):

An SPI interface is more complex electronically inside the MCU (digital host) than a simple IO line. A simple IO line that acts as chip select is by its very nature simpler than an SPI input. Hence multiple chip selects driving multiple ADCs that output onto a common/shared SPI input is preferable regards the limited resources an MCU may have.

Of course there is an even simpler mode that you haven't recognized when using multiple MAX11169s - it's called daisy chaning and all ADCs are always enabled and prompted to start a conversion together. The SDO pin of one feeds the SDI pin of the next and the final ADC in the chain feeds its SDO to the host thus, all ADCs simultaneously sample (useful for many applications) and only CLK, SDI and CONVST are needed at the host: -

[image]

Comment: Oh, I definitely considered daisy chaining...  However, I was told not to use that method for reasons I did not understand.

Comment: What kind of limitations would the MCU have? Couldn't having two cvnst lines be, in a way, construed as 2 cs pins?

Comment: Nothing wrong with daisy chaining provided your SPI bus can cope with high data rates to collect all the serial data from all ADCs between successive conversions. I don't follow your 2nd comment and I'm wary of generalizing on these types of questions.